# Financial/Scientific Calculations in Excel

Tags: excel, floating-point, scientific-computing

I was wondering how large financial or (mainly) scientific calculations would be done in Excel, given that it uses floating point numbers/calculations. For example, if there was a calculation such as:

```
12457584x10^14 * 0.000293749930049847
```

In this case, is there an Excel plug-in or something that can help to support these calculations, or do people just not do scientific (or very large financial) calculations in Excel for this reason? If so, are there any "spreadsheet-type programs" that are better suited for this purpose?

Comment: What about [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/digits.html)?

Comment: The calculation you show can be performed perfectly well in Excel as-is, without any extensions. It's not clear to me what problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: @MarkDickinson doing it in Excel only gives 8 digits of accuracy on the above calculation -- `365941442859009000.0000000`, it should be something like `36594144579650861946.3270`.

Comment: Ah, I see. The exact answer would be `365941442859009318.9648`, so it looks to me as though Excel is giving you about 15 significant digits, not 8 (which is what I'd expect, given that it's almost certainly using IEEE 754 binary64 floating-point internally). That level of accuracy is generally plenty good enough for any scientific application.

Comment: @MarkDickinson -- I see, thanks. Out of curiosity, what program did you use to do the above calculation?

Comment: I used Python (with the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html) module), and double-checked the result using [Pari/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr).

Comment: If you want to continue to use Excel and don't mind programming in VBA, you can make use of the VBA `Decimal` data type which has, I believe, 28-digit precision.  Of course, if you enter those values into an Excel cell, you must enter them as strings, since Excel itself only shows 15-digit precision.  Using VBA, the value of your calculation is: `365941442859009318.9648`  There is also an `xNumbers` add-in for Excel which is presently unsupported, but still usable, and allows even higher levels of precision.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld -- thanks, want to add this as an answer and I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue to use Excel and don't mind programming in VBA, you can make use of the VBA `Decimal` data type which has, I believe, 28-digit precision. Of course, if you enter those values into an Excel cell, you must enter them as strings, since Excel itself only shows 15-digit precision. Using VBA, the value of your calculation is: `365941442859009318.9648` There is also an `xNumbers` add-in for Excel which is presently unsupported, but still usable and findable with an internet search, and allows even higher levels of precision.